# Numpy indexing using array

Tags: multidimensional-array, numpy

I'm trying to return a (square) section from an array, where the indices wrap around the edges. I need to juggle some indexing, but it works, however, I expect the last two lines of codes to have the same result, why don't they? How does numpy interpret the last line?

And as a bonus question: Am I being woefully inefficient with this approach? I'm using the `product` because I need to modulo the range so it wraps around, otherwise I'd use `a[imin:imax, jmin:jmax, :]`, of course.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

i = np.arange(-1, 2) % 3
j = np.arange(1, 4) % 3

a = np.random.randint(1,10,(3,3,2))

print a[i,j,:]
# Gives 3 entries [(i[0],j[0]), (i[1],j[1]), (i[2],j[2])]
# This is not what I want...

indices = list(product(i, j))
print indices

indices = zip(*indices)

print 'a[indices]\n', a[indices]
# This works, but when I'm explicit:
print 'a[indices, :]\n', a[indices, :]
# Huh?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) is triggered if:

> the selection object, *obj*, is [...] a tuple with at least one sequence object or ndarray

The easiest fix in your case is to use repeated indexing:

```
a[i][:, j]
```

An alternative would be to use `ndarray.take`, which will perform the modulo operation for you if you specify `mode='wrap'`:

```
a.take(np.arange(-1, 2), axis=0, mode='wrap').take(np.arange(1, 4), axis=1, mode='wrap')
```

Answer (score 3):

To give another method of advanced indexing which is better in my opinion then the `product` solution.

If you have for every dimension an integer array these are broadcasted together and the output is the same output as the broadcast shape (you will see what I mean)...

```
i, j = np.ix_(i,j) # this adds extra empty axes

print i,j 

print a[i,j]
# and now you will actually *not* be surprised:
print a[i,j,:]
```

Note that this is a 3x3x2 array, while you had a 9x2 array, but simple reshape will fix that and the 3x3x2 array is actually closer to what you want probably.

Actually the surprise is still hidden in a way, because in your examples `a[indices]` is the same as `a[indices[0], indicies[1]]` but `a[indicies,:]` is `a[(indicies[0], indicies[1]),:]` which is not a big surprise that it is different. Note that `a[indicies[0], indicies[1],:]` does give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

See : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

When you add `:`, you are mixing integer indexing and slicing. The rules are quite complicated and better explained than I could in the above link.